# User TexBox won't handle Escape key

Tags: vb.net

I made a `MyTextMain` **custom** control

I added the property:

```
Public Property PressedEscape As Boolean = False
```

and

```
Private Sub MyTextMain_KeyUp (ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyUp 

If e.KeyCode = Keys.Escape Then Me.PressedEscape = True

End Sub
```

However, when I add a `TextBox` to any new form, the focus is on that control, I press `ESC` and the property **does not** change.

I tried the `KeyPreview` property of the form with True and False and the same.

Where is the error?

Comment: Is it really a user control or is it a custom control? A user control is specifically a class derived from `UserControl` and is basically a container for multiple child controls. If your class actually inherits `TextBox` then it is a custom control.

Comment: Sorry, it is custom control ...

Comment: When I put it on standard form, everything is ok, but if I do this on my custom form, it don't work. Something wrong is in my custom form ...

Comment: Did you check in the form property **CancelButton** status? 
this detects the escape button before the keyUp or keyDown event.

Comment: Yes, CancelButton is set to Btn_1. when I set to None everything is Ok, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Override the ProcessCmdKey in your custom TextBox control:

```
Protected Overrides Function ProcessCmdKey(ByRef msg As Message, keyData As Keys) As Boolean
  If keyData = Keys.Escape Then
    Me.PressedEscape = True
  End If
  Return MyBase.ProcessCmdKey(msg, keyData)
End Function
```

Making PressedEscape a property seems like an odd choice.  I would re-think that depending on what you are doing with it.